# RAILS 4 Syntax explanetion

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What does the assignment `||=` mean?

Comment: very basic googling could answer this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give some effort to search on google before asking on stackoverflow.

Here is quick review hope it helps you..

`:` denotes that you are using a symbol.

`@` is an instance variable on the class: it's basically a variable that's shared among all methods on an instance of a class. It has no relation to `:`

Plain old `variable_name` is a local variable and that variable is only good for as long as that method is called.

As for guides, you should read up on ruby basics or take a look at the something like this
**[difference between Ruby String and Symbol](http://www.reactive.io/tips/2009/01/11/the-difference-between-ruby-symbols-and-strings/)**

---

A common misconception is that a `||=` b is equivalent to `a = a || b`, but it behaves like `a || a = b`

In `a = a || b`, `a` is set to something by the statement on every run, whereas with `a || a = b`, `a` is only set if `a` is logically false (i.e. if it's `nil` or `false`) because || is 'short circuiting'. That is, if the left hand side of the `||` comparison is true, there's no need to check the right hand side.

For more details check this http://www.rubyinside.com/what-rubys-double-pipe-or-equals-really-does-5488.html

I hope this helps you... You can up-vote my answer or tick as accepted if this helps you to understand little bit... ;)